# reverse items in a string into an array

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm utilizing the google maps API, and I have some coordinates I've gotten in `LongLat` that I need to convert to `LatLong`

Here's the string:

```
1.5887868,50.8315241|1.5830702,50.8466931|1.590201,50.827209|1.5887868,50.8315241
```

where `1.5887868` is the first longitudinal coordinate, `50.8315241` is the first latitudinal cooridnate, and the pairs are broken up by `|`

It's my belief that I need to change the order of these paired items because google can only accept `LatLng`here, (`LngLat` causes an error)

```
center:new google.maps.LngLat(50.8315241, 1.5887868),
```

What's the easiest way to go about this?  Or - is there a way for me to use my coorinates in `long,lat` format?

Comment: How are you "using" the coordinates?

Comment: they are added into an array, then added to the `map` object by `map.data.addGeoJson(item)` - because GeoJson is `long,lat`, which makes complete sense..........  I'm using the GeoJson coords to build `LatLong` coords so I can dynamically find the center of the polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
var longLatStr = "1.5887868,50.8315241|1.5830702,50.8466931|1.590201,50.827209|1.5887868,50.8315241";

var latLongStr = longLatStr.split("|").map(function(longLatPair){
    var longLatPairArr = longLatPair.split(",");
    return longLatPairArr[1] + "," + longLatPairArr[0];
}).join('|');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can swap anything in a string with the `.replace()` function (relies on regex). For whatever you want swapped, match both by capturing each thing to be swapped in parentheses, then use `$n` in the replacement string to specify where you want it moved to. See this example:

```
var c = '1.5887868,50.8315241|1.5830702,50.8466931|1.590201,50.827209|1.5887868,50.8315241';
var swapped = c.replace(/(-?\d+\.\d+),(-?\d+\.\d+)/g, '$2,$1');
```

You can read the full documentation on using special replacement patterns on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Comment: thanks so much!  This answer works almost perfectly.  The only issue is that the regex is not capturing a negative sign *if it exists*, so `-1.58,50.831` becomes `-50.831,1.58`.  I tried changing the first part of the replace to `/(-\\d+\\.\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d+),(\\d+\\.\\d+)/` (to include the `|`), but now the swap doesn't take place.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @JohnWu You need to put the negative sign in front of both numbers and make it optional. So start each parentheses with `(-?`. I'd keep the comma instead of pipe, you were trying to switch numbers on both sides of commas I thought? Answer edited to show in example.